# Memory leak in matplotlib.plot()

Tags: python, matplotlib

**Background:**

I am writing a `Python` script which creates an animation by updating a `plt.figure` every few milliseconds. I have noticed that the memory usage is increasing slowly but safely to indefinite.

After some debugging, I was able to reduce the problem to the following standalone example:

- Create a `Figure`.
- Connect to a mouse event, and call `ax.plot()` in loop. **Note** that I call `remove()` immediately after, and asserting that there is exactly one artist to remove.

Running this example and clicking on plot area, memory usage will start climbing fast.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class LeakTest:

    def __init__(self):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.cid = self.fig.canvas.callbacks.connect('button_press_event', self.start_leaking)
        plt.show()

    def start_leaking(self, event):
        xarr, yarr = [1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 9]  # zip(*arrow_pts)
        for i in range(1000000):
            print(i)
            plot = self.ax.plot(xarr, yarr, color='red')
            assert isinstance(plot, list)
            assert len(plot) == 1
            plot[0].remove()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tt = LeakTest()
```

Any idea why, or how to fix?

**Edit:**

- I am using Python 3.6 on Windows. PyCharm.
- matplotlib==3.3.4
- Default backend (Qt5Agg)
- **Most important, I forgot - leaking only starts on mousee-press-event:**

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce using `mprof` to diagnose the memory and Qt5Agg as the backend, using my Mac.  What backend are you using?

Comment: What IDE are you using? I can reproduce this in Jupyter, but this is what I'd call expected behaviour in that environment, and it's an issue with Jupyter, not matplotlib. Jupyter doesn't seem to garbage collect properly, even when forced. The issue is not reproducible in PyCharm.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Thanks for your help. Added an edit to the question.

Comment: @JodyKlymak hanks for your help. Added an edit to the question.

Comment: I did click the mouse to start the iteration. PyCharm Pro Version: 2021.1.2, matplotlib 3.4.2, python 3.8. I recommend that you update.

Comment: Yes I also clicked to start the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, running with matplotlib **3.3.4** reproduces the error. Running with matplotlib **3.4.2** does not.

So the solution is to upgrade matplotlib.